Change text on hover with CSS
I'm trying to make text change when hovering over an image with CSS (elementor pro).
I'm making something that looks like a color swatch, that when hovering over another color of the product, it changes the text above it to the color the cursor is hovering over, and changing it back to the normal text when not hovering over it.
The issue I have now is that the radius of the hovering is too big, is expands over the whole container instead of only the small image/swatch.
Thanks!
I added this CSS code and added the class: text to the container I want the text to appear.
.text:before {
    content: "Kies je kleur: Gun Metal";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text:hover::before {
    content: "Kies je kleur: Rosé Gold";
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example



.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
.img-wrapper:before{
  content: 'img 1'
}
.img-wrapper:hover:before{
  content: 'new'
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1693572774544-bbca04f96800?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" height="50px" width="50px" />
  </div>
   <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1693572774544-bbca04f96800?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" height="50px" width="50px" />
  </div>
   <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1693572774544-bbca04f96800?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" height="50px" width="50px" />
  </div>
</div>




I'm a huge noob to coding, not sure how to implement this into elementor

@casvanheer please share the HTML you are using in elementor

To be honest I did not add HTML into elementor, just added the lines of CSS and gave the container a CSS class. And it did work in a way, but the hover effect works on the whole container with that class, and not only the image

so you basically needs to add hover to the class which wraps the image and the element which contains the text
